# How can I correct the error Cannot be resolved or not a field error

Tags: java, android

I have cleaned and deleted the import R file and I still get quarter, dime, nickel, and penny Cannot be resolved or is not a field error.  Those four lines continue to draw that error. I've just learning Java so I have not a clue of what to do to clear this error. Please help?
Thank You

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int quarter = getResources().getInteger(R.quarter);
    int dime = getResources().getInteger(R.dime);
    int nickel = getResources().getInteger(R.nickel);
    int penny = getResources().getInteger(R.penny);
    int entry = Integer.parseInt(theTextWord.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using **`R.id`**  to access the id of the XML elements.

```
  R.id.yourIdHere
```

Or if you they are saved as integer resources, then use **`R.integer.yourIdHere`**

Answer (score 0):

If these are saved as an `integer` `resource` then it should be

```
int quarter = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.quarter);
```

[Integer resource Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing resources from xml files depends on how they are declared in the xml file.  I'm guessing that your integer resources are defined something like:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="quarter">25</integer>   <!-- notice the resource declaration 'integer' -->
    <integer name="dime">10</integer>
    ...
</resources>
```

In which case you would want to refer to them as

```
R.integer.quarter
R.integer.dime
```

If the declaration is something else like 'string' use that instead [of course, getting an integer in your code from a string is bound to cause problems :)]

Some further information about [Android resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)